# Application/Window icon is not getting displayed in QAT RibbonControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

I am working with a WPF application where I have a Ribbon. I also have a Quick Access Toolbar (QAT). As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6K0e.png) the window/application icon is not being displayed, rather that place is empty.

I searched a lot, I even tried RibbonWindow and still the place is empty in QAT. Kindly let me know if I am missing any property that I should set?

My xaml:

```
    <r:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
        <r:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar  CanUserCustomize="True" >
           <r:RibbonButton Command="{StaticResource cmdAddNew}" Name="qaAddNew" r:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar.Placement="InCustomizeMenuAndToolBar" />
           <r:RibbonButton Command="{StaticResource cmdSave}"   r:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar.Placement="InCustomizeMenuAndToolBar" />
           <r:RibbonButton Command="{StaticResource cmdClose}" Name="qaClose" r:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar.Placement="InCustomizeMenuAndToolBar" />
           <r:RibbonButton Command="{StaticResource cmdReset}"  r:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar.Placement="InCustomizeMenuAndToolBar" />
        </r:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>           
    </r:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
```

Comment: Are you setting the `Icon` in the RibbonWindow?

Comment: @MattL. It is nt making any difference whether I using it or not.

Comment: As long as your XAML looks something like `<Window <!-- Namespaces, etc. --> Icon="your image here">` (Or RibbonWindow) and if the icon still isn't showing up, then you must be changing the style of it somewhere in your code

Comment: I checked but I have nowhere changed the style of Window.